# vim plugin for directory list/file open

Tags: vim, editor

I'm looking for a vim plugin similar to http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1325 with a directory list in which you can select a file to open. Does this exist somewhere? Wasn't able to find it myself.

Comment: Do you mean something like NERDTree?

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to be able to open it with lets say F4 and close it by hitting F4 again. Maybe a wrapper on top of NERDTree?

Comment: You can make a mapping in your `.vimrc` to toggle NERDTree `map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) is the second best ranked plugin on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) and it perfectly fits your description.

There are many other variations of the same principle:

- [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)
- [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) (the one I used before)
- [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) (famous among TextMate switchers, I never liked it, though)
- [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) (the one I use now)
- …

And I second `:Explore`.

Comment: Thank you. NERDTree is exactly what I was looking for. Something that would mimic the useful left pane as in kate, but this a fairly flexible.

Comment: Well… I do't find it useful at all but if you are happy, I'm happy.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the :Explore command that comes with the standard vim distribution since (roughly) version 6?

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_explorer for basic help on that command.

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-quickhelp for detailed help on what the Explorer can do.

If you want to open an explorer without replacing the current buffer, you can use the :Sexplore command.  A puerile mnemonic for that is to execute :Sex.